# Email not working Magento Community version 1.9.3.8

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-cron, php-5.6

My store is developed in  1.9.3.8 and none of the emails working like: Order confirmation email, Contact us mail, new registration mail, forget password mail.

I tried sending through the admin panel but nothing happens, also no update email is being received. Can anyone help me with this problem for Magento 1.9.3.8?

Thanks

Comment: Have you correctly configured SMTP in your server ??

Comment: Cron needs to be running also, for email queue to be sent out.

Comment: I have setup cron and it running properly but email is not working

Comment: Murtuza Zabuawala  I'm using localhost server for send email there no any third party email service

Comment: I am also facing same issue..No any mail.. there is not other smtp..Only localhost default  am using.